# How does CRM 2011 auto-wire the StringMapBase table in for Option List picks in Advanced Finds?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services, crm

The StringMapBase SQL table is the table that holds Option List values that have been added to an entity. When using an Advanced Find in CRM 2011, if you select a pick list column (Option List) value from an entity to be added to the resultset, the Advanced Find mechanism somehow auto-wires in the string value of the pick list from the StringMapBase table instead of showing the StringMapBase's Primary Key value that's actually stored on the record.

I'm in the process of creating SSRS reports that hinge on some Option List values:

```
// SQL psuedocode
Select...
...
Where Value = 'Some String Value of Interest'
```

However, I very much dislike the fact that, so far, it looks like I basically have to write in some ad-hoc SQL in order to get the applicable StringMapBase value. In order to do so, I have to hard-code some magic values, which I despise.

Does anyone know by what mechanism the CRM Advanced Find engine auto-wires these values in? Or does it simply do its own join to the StringMap system view or use a SPROC somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Filtered views (the only supported way to read data in your report) there will be an additional "logical" column for Bit, Picklist, and Lookup columns.  For an attribute named "new_option" you should be able to add "name" to the end of the column name and query "new_optionname".

```
select new_option, -- Integer
       new_optionname -- StringMap joins generated by Filtered Views
from   Filterednew_test
```